# Bash - delete rows from one file while iterating through rows from another file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I have two files.

`file.txt` and `delete.txt`

`file.txt` contains the following for ex.:

```
/somedirectory/
/somedirectory2/somefile.txt
/anotherfile.txt
```

`delete.txt` contains:

```
/somedirectory/
/somedirectory2/somefile.txt
```

I need to delete the rows from `file.txt` that are contained within `delete.txt`

`cat file.txt` should result with:

```
/anotherfile.txt
```

So far I've tried this with no luck:

```
while read p; do
    line=$p;
    sed -i '/${line}/d' file.txt;
done < delete.txt
```

I don't receive any error, it just doesn't edit my `file.txt` file. I've tested the while loop with an `echo ${line}` and it works as expected in that scenario.

Any suggestions?

Note: the while loop above doesn't work as expected even when I took the forward slashes off of the files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a simple `grep`:

```
grep -vFxf  delete.txt file.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt file.txt
```

Comment: while heemayl and rom1v 's answers actually get the output I want, your answer was complete since I wanted to update the file.txt file which you provided. It's also simpler. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]=1; next}; !a[$0]' delete.txt file.txt
```

- `NR==FNR {a[$0]=1; next}` is only executed for the `delete.txt` file (first file argument); associative array `a` has the records as keys, and `1` as the value for every key
- `!a[$0]` is executed for the second file argument i.e. `file.txt`; printing (default action) the record(s) that are not present in the array `a` as key(s)

**Example:**

```
% cat delete.txt 
/somedirectory/
/somedirectory2/somefile.txt

% cat file.txt
/somedirectory/
/somedirectory2/somefile.txt
/anotherfile.txt

% awk 'NR==FNR {a[$0]=1; next}; !a[$0]' delete.txt file.txt
/anotherfile.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

The ${line} inside the single quotes will not get expanded, so it would be looking for the actual string ${line} in file.txt.   Put that into your sample file to see if it gets removed.

However, you'll still have problems because the slashes inside delete text will get interpreted by sed, so the regular expression won't get properly delimited.   You'd have to jump through some hoops to get every character in your input line properly quoted as literal in order to use sed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `comm` instead:

```
comm -23 file.txt delete.txt
```

The input files must be sorted, though. If they are not:

```
comm -23 <(sort file.txt) <(sort delete.txt)
```